# mvc if modelstate.isValid return view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I'm positive the solution its simple..

so i have a problem that i have a form in the following url

www.url.com/Modify/12423?Type=bananas

i have a custom validation in entity of the form to see if a date is bigger than the other.. so when i post the form

```
  if(ModelState.IsValid){
                ... do stufs
         } 
        else
        {

            return View(new { Type= "bananas"});


        }
```

if ill do this.. we will return to the url
www.url.com/Modify/12423 and it will miss the Type bananas on it..

any solution?

or how to put the custom validation in the clientside instead of going to the if(modelstate.isvalid)

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to create a route that includes the type parameter in it: `routes.MapRoute("ModifyType","Modify/{Id}/{Type}, new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction"})"`